# Cannot create sharepoint site under web application using central administration

Tags: site-creation

I am trying to create a new web application and create a site under that. I have created web application and site collection but I cannot add site to site collection. I tried to add but it is adding in web application that is running central administration. Any Ideas? I am using SharepPoint 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a child-site to an existing Site Collection, you don't do that from Central Admin. Log on to the top site of the site-collection, and create your sub-sites from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response EtherDragon!!! Right after creating site collection, I am trying to open the top level site but it throws error in browser.. and I assign myself as admin to the site collection so I don't think there is any permission issue...

Comment: Thanks!! The problem was probably that the we chose server name that was not mapped to any IP. and it didn't complain that server not found or something... we provided correct server name and it worked!!!